# ¿Utilizar metodo Chunk de laravel en un stored procedure?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server, laravel-5, php7

Tengo un sp(Store Procedure) que me devuelve 100 000 registros, pero al imprimirlos en el  DataTable se demora demasiado he estado investigando  como optimizar la carga de los datos y me encontre con Chunk, el problema que tengo es que no  se como inplementarlo.

```
 public function genealogy(Request $request,$abi){
    $id = $abi;
    try {

        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        $period='201909';

        $conection = \DB::connection('sqlsrvgenealogy');

        $datas= $conection->select('EXEC Sp_TreePerId ?,?', array($id, $period));


        \DB::disconnect('sqlsrvgenealogy');

        $data = $datas->chunk(30);

        return DataTables::of($data)->make(true);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo($e->getMessage());

    }


}
```

Lo tengo  de esta manera pero me envia el siguiete error .

> Call to a member function chunk() on array

Esta es la forma en que utilizo  el data table, estoy utilizando de ingual forma `"deferRender": true,` pero a mi punto  de vista no  me esta funcionando ya que demora lo mismo al cargar los datos.

```
var table =  $('#genealogy_tab').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "pageLength": 30,
        "stateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "genealogy/{{ $ids }}",
        "deferRender": true,
        columns:[
          {data: 'Line'},
          {data: 'Level'},
          {data: 'associateid'},
          {data: 'associatename'},
          {data: 'Distributor_status'},
          {data: 'email'},
          {data: 'mobile_number'},
          {data: 'country'},
          {data: 'PinRank'},
          {data: 'PayRank'},
          {data: 'InactiveMonths'},
          {data: 'RenewalDate'},
        ],
        "language": {
                      "sProcessing":     "Processing...",
                      "sLengthMenu":     " _MENU_ ",
                      "sZeroRecords":    "No results found",
                      "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                      "sInfo":           "Showing records  _START_ of _END_ from a total of _TOTAL_ records",
                      "sInfoEmpty":      "Showing records 0 of 0 from a total of 0 records",
                      "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                      "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                      "sSearch":         "Search:",
                      "sUrl":            "",
                      "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                      "sLoadingRecords": "Loading Records...",
                      "oPaginate": {
                          "sFirst":    "First",
                          "sLast":     "Last",
                          "sNext":     "Next",
                          "sPrevious": "Previous"
                      },
                      "oAria": {
                          "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                          "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                      }
                  },

                    dom: 'Bfrtip',

                    buttons: [
                      {
                          extend:    'excelHtml5',
                          text:      'Excel',
                          titleAttr: 'Excel',
                          className: 'btn '
                      },
                      {
                          extend:    'csvHtml5',
                          text:      'CSV',
                          titleAttr: 'CSV',
                          className: 'btn '
                      },
                      {
                          extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                          orientation: 'landscape',
                          pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                          text:      'PDF',
                          titleAttr: 'PDF',
                          className: 'btn '
                      },
                      {
                          extend:    'print',
                          text:      'Print',
                          titleAttr: 'Print',
                          className: 'btn '
                      },
                       {
                            extend: 'colvis',
                            postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
                        }
                    ]
      });
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muestra la clase  `DataTables`

Comment: Si esa es tu funcion, porque no simplemente lo cambias a un ajax normal?, retornas un objeto json en tu controlador de laravel y cargas los datos solo con javascript.

Comment: ¿Que hace el SP que no pueda hacer en PHP o con una query?

Comment: @EmmanuelGomez, es algo largo de explicar, ni siquiera sé  si tienes los archivos. intenta buscando cosas relacionadas, busca DataTables por separado, sin laravel y se que lo lograras. un ejemplo: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXyazm